# MS Access shortcut key to open database with navigation pane open

Tags: ms-access, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the keyboard shortcut that allows you to open an Access database (.accdb) with the Navigation pane open, when startup options are set to have it closed? I used to do this all the time, but can't remember or find the correct keys.
I'm not looking for F11, opening the pane after opening the database. It opens basically bypassing the startup option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to hold SHIFT key in keyboard while access db getting opened.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out the programmer(s) has a bunch of functions and macros working behind the scenes enabling and disabling features in some kind of spaghetti fashion. Oh well, and welcome to SE!

Comment: See this to remove this option: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/miscellaneous/allowbypasskey-property